# Google App Engine NDB - "Update or Insert (if not exists)"

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am trying to do the equivalent of an "Update or Insert (if not exists)".

Any idea how to do this? The only solution I can come up with was to do a GQL query, then either update returned records, or create a new one if none was returned from the query.

This method would not be atomic - but I am wondering if there was a "simple" way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no atomic operations as such.  You need to use transactions.

How about reading the docs, both db and ndb have a method for 'get or insert' which is transactional and then you do the update/apply of values to properties inside a transaction and then write (put()) the entity.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert

Also remember queries results are subject to "eventual" consistency unless they are ancestor queries.

Read more about transactions https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions

Answer (score 2):

If you have the key, just get, update, and put within a transaction.  There's no "update" operation in GAE's datastore, it's just read the entity, and write the entity.

Comment: So #1 How do I get the key. Can I "build" it knowing a field, or so I have to do a GQL query. #2 - What you are describing is not in itself atomic.

Comment: #1 really depends.  If you used some identifier that you know (ie email addr) as the key, then you know it.  Otherwise you might need to query for the entity first to get the key, then refetch inside the transaction.  #2 The operations in themselves are not atomic, you need to put in a transaction.  On the other hand, that's all you need to do.